# Android Studio Remove lint error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.0, android-lint

I need to remove a lint error and I don't know how to do that.
The problem is that lint is interpreting wrong a regex expression. As the expression is in UTF-16, the range is right, but it interprets it as UTF-8 then it detects an Illegal character range (from < to) exception on my EMOJI_REGEX . Although the lint error, the code is working fine, so I need to remove that lint error. How could I do that?

```
private final static String EMOJI_REGEX = "([\\u20a0-\\u32ff\\ud83c\\udc00-\\ud83d\\udeff\\udbb9\\udce5-\\udbb9\\udcee])";
```

I have tried:

```
@SuppressLint("all")
```

but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check [suppressing-lint-warnings](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:right click in file,Analyse->InspectCode. Select Current File -> Ok. Now you will see Lint issues. Select yours and see what suggestions you have (like supress or remove (on right click on the issue).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried that and @SuppressWarnings("MalformedRegex") is added, but the error label is still there :(

Comment: On Android Studio 2.1.1 I have no error on that line of code, so I can't help more, sorry. Anyway, sometimes, cleaning and rebuilding the project can suppress fake error labels.

Comment: Updating Android Studio to 2.2 solved the problem. Thanks a lot!